# Dynamodb query efficiently

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb table called "Users":

Primary Key: UserId (uniquely generated internally)
Sort Key: Email
Attribute: Friends (type M) --> UserId, Status

So, for one user record, it could look like this:

UserId: 000001

Email: myname@domain.com

```
       Friends
       -------
       UserId: 00008    Status: Active
       UserId: 00010    Status: Active
```

If I would like to query and change the status for a given UserId in the "Friends" Attribute and not knowing the value of the Primary Key, what would be the best practice way to either change the structure of the table or query technique? I was told that "Scan" is not recommended for large tables.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this NoSql is very new to me.

Comment: If you want to query in dynamodb and avoid the "scan" then you need to create a global (or local) secondary index. unfortunately you cannot create an index on a map attribute if you re looking to query user ids in the map attribute "friends" . You need to think how to restructure your database schema.

Comment: @gijoe thank you for your response. Yes, that is what is bugging me at the moment on how to create a multi list of "friends" for a given UserId

Comment: this is an personal architectural decision, but the simplest way would be to create a new table that would hold the friends of a User called=>Users_Friends and it will have a global secondary index with hash key UserId (and maybe also you can use a range key the "Status" field so you can find with one query all the friends of user that are active or inactive )

Comment: @gijoe I did think of having another table for the friends, but management thinks they can get away with just one table. And yes, a second table to hold the friends would be easier for querying

Comment: friend is bidirectional relationship right?

Comment: @MrNobody, yes friend is bidirectional in the sense that the both have each other's UserId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to update the status of a user's friend, but you only know the friend's ID.  From your question, it looks like your data is stored as follows:

[image]

In this table, you've chosen to model the one-to-many relationship between a User and their Friends as a map.  This is a valid way to model this one-to-many relationship.  However, this approach has limitations, as you are discovering.

If all you needed to do was list a users friends, this may be sufficient.  However, if you have any access patterns that require you to search by the items inside the Friends map, you'll find that pattern rather limiting.

One way to fix this is to model the User to Friends relationship in item *collections*:

[image]

In this example, I'm introducing item *collections* that group more than one type of relationship under the same partition key.
I've also renamed the Partition Key and Sort Key to PK and SK respectively since I'm using those fields more generically now.  A few things I'd like to point out:

- PK = 000001 represents the User *item collection*.  This collection contains information about a user and the user's friendships.
- PK = 000001 SK = user1@gmail.com is the User *item*.
- PK = 000001 SK = FRIEND00002 is an item that represents the friendship between user 000001 and 000002.
- You can fetch all the friends of User 000001 by executing a `query` operation where the PK= 000001 and the SK `begins_with` FRIEND.

Now that we have the data arranged in this way, we can more easily address your access pattern.  For example, we could create a secondary index that swaps the PK and SK fields of your primary table.  This is called an "inverted index".  Using the example above, your secondary index would logically look like this.

[image]

Keep in mind this is the same data, just a different view of the data.

With this secondary index, you can execute a single [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) operation to update the `status` of any particular friendship.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of everything. I will definitely try to digest this. I am coming from an RDS mind, so this takes some switching of the brain to grasp. I can't thank you enough for this response, Seth.

Comment: Glad to hear!  If it helped, consider accepting it as the answer to the question (or mark the answer as useful).  DDB is totally different than RDS systems, it definitely takes some getting used to.

Comment: Hi Seth, Using the collections in the above example, how would you create your params in the Lambda to add a new user record using the PutItem? My current flow is that Friends can come at a later time after the user is created.

Comment: params = { "TableName": "Users",
                  "Item": { 
                                "PK": {"S": "<user id here>"},
                                "SK":{ "S": "<user email here>"}
                              }
                 }

Comment: Thank you very much, Seth. I think I get the idea now.

Comment: Last question Seth, querying for friends in the example will return results with the “FRIENDS#” prefix. What would be the recommended way to output the data without the prefix, basically a substring of the value? Thanks in advance, Seth..

Comment: The sort key is just for DynamoDB to arrange your data to fit your applications access patterns.  I wouldn't necessarily recommend parsing the key to extract information.  Instead, just store the fields you want in the items attributes.  In the above example, if you fetched all the friends for User 000001 (query where PK= 0000001 and SK begins_with FRIEND), you would have a status attribute.  Theres no reason you couldn't add more attributes (e.g. friend_id, type, favorite_color, etc).

Comment: Fantastic, Seth! Thank you again for the clarification. You saved the day!